# React: Is it a good practice to handle state updates in a service function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Taking as an example a dummy Blog app where posts are displayed on the page.

At some point, you can update a post body. The code I would produce would look like that:

```
// services
import { updatePost } from './postServices.js';

const Blog = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  ...

  const handleUpdatePost = (newBody) => {
    updatePost(postId, newBody posts, setPosts)
      .catch((error) => // handle error )
  };

  ...

  return (
    ...
  )

};
```

Where the `updatePost` function would look like that:

```
export const updatePost = async (postId, newBody, posts, setPosts) => {
  const result = await axios.post(`posts/${postId}`, { body: newBody });
  
  // handling the state update here
  const { updatedPost } = result.data;
  const copyPosts = [...posts];
  const post = copyPosts.find((post) => post.id === updatedPost.id);
  post.body = updatedPost.body;
  setPosts(copyPosts);
};
```

I like this approach because it keeps the react component clean and easily understandable. On the other hand, it requires passing the entire `posts` array and its `setState`, which I heard might not be too good (for performance reasons?).

My question is: would that code be considered as good or are there any pitfalls that I don't understand?

Comment: Don't think there are any performance-related issues with this approach. However, I would prefer using a custom hook to isolate the logic of state update. I would move the `posts` state inside the custom hook. You could also create a resuable hook for making the HTTP requests and use this hook inside the other custom hook that manages `posts` state.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Would you create a custom hook specifically for this `post` state? I'm not used to custom hooks, but I read that for a custom hook to be good it needs to be reusable over the app. What's your take on that?

Comment: Hook that makes the HTTP requests could be re-used in the whole app (even in other projects) and it is ok if the hook that manages the `posts` state is only used by one component.